# SQL Server NOT EXISTS from more than one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I need to return rows if exists, if not return which one of the passed value is NOT EXISTS:

```
DECLARE @INPUT1 BIGINT
DECLARE @INPUT2 BIGINT
DECLARE @INPUT3 BIGINT

SELECT e.Name, d.Name, c.Name
   FROM Employee e
   JOIN Department d ON e.DeptID = d.DeptID
   JOIN City c ON e.CityID = c.CityID
WHERE
   e.EmpID = @INPUT1
   AND d.DeptID = @INPUT2
   AND c.CityID = @INPUT3
```

In the above SQL, all the inputs INPUT1, INPUT2, INPUT3 are correctly passed in, returns the row. If NOT, I need to find which INPUTx is wrong. I know I could write 3 different Exists Queries to find which one is NOT exists. Is there a better approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how can you know for sure which one is wrong.  What if they pass in a valid employee, a valid department and a valid city, but they just aren't all valid together.  How do you know which one (or more) was "incorrect"?

Comment: I was going on the assumption that OP meant that 1 or more of those 3 values don't exist.  *Wrong* is probably not the right way to describe it: perhaps *not found* would have been better.

Comment: MJB -- Edited based on your comment (Not Exists)

Comment: Thanks Eric Petroelije -- Agreed. But in my case I just want to know only if it is NOT EXIST. All aren't valid does not work in my real scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the (inner) join, because that would eliminate those records that do not match up.  Therefore you would have to use an outer join.  Given that, it would likely be faster to use 3 queries anyway.  Actually, 4, because you would need 3 to check the 3 values, then another to return the one you want if it exists.

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 'Employee Exists' as Result from Employee where EmpId = @INPUT1
union
SELECT 'Department Exists' from Department where DeptId = @INPUT2
union
SELECT 'City Exists' from City where CityId = @INPUT3
```

to show which ones DO NOT exist, and then return what does with the query you have.  And I guess you could combine that into 3 columns instead of 3 rows, but it would still be 3 queries.

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic you want is unclear, but this construct applies the filter as a derived table and you can left join against it. So if d.Name isnull then no match on @INPUT2

```
DECLARE @INPUT1 BIGINT, @INPUT2 BIGINT, @INPUT3 BIGINT

SELECT
    @INPUT1 AS NotThereIf_eName_IsNull,
    @INPUT2 AS NotThereIf_dName_IsNull,
    @INPUT3 AS NotThereIf_cName_IsNull,
    e.Name, d.Name, c.Name
FROM
    (SELECT @INPUT1 AS EmpID,  @INPUT2 AS DeptID, @INPUT3 AS CityID) dummy
    LEFT JOIN 
    Employee e ON dummy.EmpID = e.EmpID
    LEFT JOIN 
    Department d ON dummy.DeptID = d.DeptID AND e.DeptID = d.DeptID
    LEFT JOIN 
    City c ON dummy.CityID = c.CityID AND e.CityID = c.CityID
```